# Search folder hierarchy in FileNet for a particular folder

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet-content-engine

I am new to accessing FileNet CE from Java.

From my test program, I can connect, create folders, upload files and retrieve the list.

Now, I need to find a folder within the ObjectStore. That is to say, given a hierarchy of folders within folders:
Folder1
-- Folder1a
-- Folder1b
---- Folder1b1
---- Folder1b2
-- Folder1c
---- Folder1c1
---- Folder1c2
Folder2
...

How do I search for a folder given its name? It could be N levels deep.

Similarly, how do I search using wildcards in the name?

Similarly, I created a sub-class of a folder (PersonnelFolder) and gave it some attributes (Personnel ID, Department, etc.). How do I search for a Personnel ID? i.e. Search in properties within objects of a given class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching on the [Documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGLW6_5.2.0/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.ce.doc/containment_procedures.htm), there are no examples about it, just snippet of code that address specific paths.
Like this:

**Get the parent folder of a subpath:**

```
String childFolderPath = "/Loans/MyLoans";
Folder currentFolder = Factory.Folder.fetchInstance(os, childFolderPath, null);
Folder parent = currentFolder.get_Parent();
```

**Get the folders directly contained in a path**

```
String folderPath = "/Loans";
Folder currentFolder = Factory.Folder.fetchInstance(os, folderPath, null);
FolderSet childFolders = currentFolder.get_SubFolders();
```

By the way, doing a research via FEM, it's easy to build a sql that addresses only part of the name. Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM [Folder] WHERE ([FolderName] like '%Folder1a%')
```

Similarly with a custom metadata:

```
SELECT * FROM [YourFolderSubType] WHERE ([YourCustomAttribute] = 'yourValue')
```

Then, accessing the attribute `PathName` gives you the complete path. Or, alternatively, you could just retrieve its `ID` in order to fetch the Folder object from it.

You could try to execute a query like these from the APIs, then cast each result as a Folder object in order to work on it.

An example (untested):

```
SearchSQL sqlObject = new SearchSQL(sqlStatement);
RepositoryRowSet rowSet = searchScope.fetchRows(sqlObject, null, null, new Boolean(true));
Iterator iter = myRows.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    RepositoryRow row = (RepositoryRow) iter.next();
    row.getProperties().getStringValue("ID");
    com.filenet.api.core.Folder folder = Factory.Folder.fetchInstance(os, id, null);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. Got the code to work. The "Folder" table finds folders that are nested as well as custom folders. I'll try your custom metadata code too. Question: Which columns does the "Folder" table have? Do you have a link to the docs? Question: From your code I see that a custom folder class has its own table. Correct? So such a folder would appear in the "Folder" table as well as the "CustomFolder" table? Also, a link to the "Document" table?

Comment: Glad to help. Here's the documentation for Folder: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSNW2F_5.5.0/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.java.doc/com/filenet/api/core/Folder.html. Note that if you install FEM or ACCE you can test your queries and view objects beforehand. To your questions: Yes, custom folders are independent classes, but they inherits from Folder (they are subclasses of it); so yes, search on "Folders" will retrieve them too; and no, "Document" is separated from "Folder".

Comment: Test them beforehand? That would be a great time-saver. How?
No, of course I know that Document & Folder are different classes. I meant, do you have a link showing the structure of the Folder and Document classes.

Comment: No, unfortunately I don't have the structure as example. But, regarding the UI I was talking about, you can usually access ACCE with server_address:port/acce (where server address and port are CE ones) and FEM is a (now deprecated) client that you can install on Windows. Search for "Filenet Enterprise Manager".