# Searching for a folder in FileNet ContentEngine and retrieving its class

Tags: java, filenet-p8, filenet-content-engine

I had gotten the code to work to search for folders and retrieve properties. Ref: [Search folder hierarchy in FileNet for a particular folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56098141/search-folder-hierarchy-in-filenet-for-a-particular-folder/)

I am trying to retrieve the class name of the folder object so as to differentiate between different types of docs that will get stored in custom folders.

I iterated thru the Properties collection, but the name of the class isn't a property.

```
String sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM [Folder] WHERE ([FolderName] LIKE '%MyFolder%')";
SearchSQL sqlObject = new SearchSQL(sqlStatement);
RepositoryRowSet rowSet = searchScope.fetchRows(sqlObject, null, null, new Boolean(true));
Iterator iter = myRows.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    RepositoryRow row = (RepositoryRow) iter.next();
    String folderID = row.getProperties().getIdValue("ID").toString();
}
```

I tried row.getClass() but that just returns: RepositoryRowImpl

Comment: From any object, we write obj.getClass().getName() provides class name, in this case, what are you expecting ? Are you expecting a Folder object and its class name ?

Comment: Yes, I was expecting "Folder" or "MyCustomFolder" as the name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use the `*` in your SELECT clause then the repository row object will contain all the properties of the object. This will also include a property called `This`. This property is a reference to the object that is returned. Therefore you can use the following code to fetch the class of the folder:

```
EngineObject eo = row.getProperties().getEngineObjectValue("This");
String className = eo.getClassName();
```

Instead of the `*` you can also explicitly select `This`. In that case your query will be like this:

```
String sqlStatement = "SELECT This,Id FROM [Folder] WHERE ([FolderName] LIKE '%MyFolder%')";
```

This will limit the amount of data that is fetched from the server.

Comment: Ofcourse. Agreed. I only use * during testing.
I tried this: 
ClassDescription objClassDesc = (ClassDescription) rrRow.getProperties().getObjectValue("ClassDescription");
String className =  objClassDesc.get_Name();

This also gives me the expected class name of the folder. Which is the recommended / faster method?

Comment: The Class Description is in another table then the Folder object. So this gives you a overhead from a query perspective. Besides the name of the class, the Class Description object comes filed with a lot of other information your are not interested in, giving you an overhead from the data perspective.

Comment: BTW, I tried accessing DB/2 databases directly using the CLI. Can't find this, or any other table. Where are the tables in DB/2?

Comment: @Ricardo That does not mean there is no additional round-trip associated with `getEngineObjectValue("This")`. I am pretty sure there is. But this should be specifically examined. Unfortunately, CE API makes a lot of implicit round-trips behind the scene.